# Running SymmetricDS as a Service on CentOS

Tags: java, linux, centos, symmetricds

I have successfully installed SymmetricDS on CentOS 6.3 64 bits. I can launch it :

```
../bin/sym --port 8080 --server
```

Now I am trying to launch it as a service.

I followed the instructions of :

http://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.2/html/advanced-topics.html#running-service

The command

```
/etc/init.d/sym_service status
```

returns

> SymmetricDS is not running.

When I issue :

```
/etc/init.d/sym_service start
```

I get

```
Starting SymmetricDS/etc/init.d/sym_service: /opt/symmetric-ds/bin/sym_service: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Any clues ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The service packaged with SymmetricDS is using the x86 32-bit version of Java Service Wrapper. You'll want to download the latest version of JSW for your platform, which is Linux x86 64-bit community edition found here:

http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp

Then copy the files into place:

```
jsw/bin/wrapper -> symmetricds/bin/sym_service
jsw/lib/wrapper.jar -> symmetricds/lib/wrapper.jar
jsw/lib/libwrapper.so -> symmetricds/lib/libwrapper.so
```

Comment: Works like a charm on CentOS 6.3